# Manually flagging memory pages as 'dirty'

Tags: c++, linux, paging, mmap, throughput

While sequentially modifying a huge (~65GB) memory mapped file residing on a hard disk on Linux, I noticed the following behavior:

- If I modify almost everything in the file (I'm guessing at least one byte on every memory page), the read/write throughput is about 40MB/s
- If I modify only some pages while leaving other unchanged, the read/write thoughput is **reduced** dramatically, to about 7MB/s

So changing fewer things actually reduces the througput. The process is massively I/O bound (5% CPU time is `user`, 95% CPU time is `iowait`), so the actual processing taking place cannot account for the throughput difference. My guess is that the kernel paging system uses sequential writes in the first case, and random access writes in the latter. The resulting frequent seeking would account for the performance difference.

If I force modification of data on every page (e.g. by swapping some least significant bits), performance increases to the 40MB/s level, but this approach corrupts the data. Effective NOOPs like XOR'ing the data on the page twice with a fixed pattern has no effect on performance (I used `objdump` to verify that the code is not eliminated by the compiler). My guess here is that the double XOR is handled completely inside the CPU cache, and since the second XOR restores the original data, no changes ever reach the actual RAM, thus keeping the underlying memory page clean.

So is there a way to improve the throughput in the second case? Specifically, is there a way to make the kernel write back even select clean pages, or to robustly manually mark pages as dirty programatically?

Comment: If you modify something on every page, then the system can combine writes, resulting in sequential write-out performance. If you only touch a few pages here and there, the write-out performance is going to look a lot more like random writes, with the corresponding decrease in perceived performance. But, if you only touch e.g. 1% of the pages, the time to write out everything should still be considerably less than if you touch every page, even though the rate of writing seems much lower.

Comment: Yeah, that explains why the issue occurs. But it does not help me work around it without corrupting the data...

Comment: Have You tried interlocked NOOPs? For example InterlockedCompareExchange(ptr, 0, 0). This instruction generates write cycle even when no data is written. But I do not know how does this affect dirty bits. I even wonder why normal XOR leaves dirty bit unchanged.